# What is the minimum SO_RCVBUF value?

Tags: c, networking, udp, buffer, system-calls

To minimize latency (I don't care about packet loss) I want the smallest possible receive buffer for UDP. However, when I set SO_RCVBUF to below 1000 (with setsockopt), my program never receives any packets. The datagrams I am sending have 28 bytes of data, for a total on-wire packet size of 70 bytes, so why can I not receive anything if SO_RCVBUF is < 1000? And how do I change this, to allow a smaller buffer size?

Additionally, is it possible to set the buffer in terms of number of packets, rather than bytes? Or is there some way I can manually empty it?

Comment: Why do you think reducing the receive buffer size is going to reduce the latency?

Comment: @Nikolai because it takes me 2ms to process each packet, during which time any others are just sitting in the buffer. So if two packets arrive together, one of them gets +2ms added onto it's apparent latency.

Comment: Dequeue all available packets each time?

Comment: @Nikolai yes, that would do it - how do I do that? Also like to know why though...

Comment: Non-blocking socket, edge-triggered `epoll` or `kqueue`, on "readable" event read until you get `EWOULDBLOCK`.

Comment: As to why, look here - http://vger.kernel.org/~davem/skb_sk.html, and here - http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.37/include/net/sock.h#L621

Comment: @Nikolai can you post your comments as an answer, so that I can accept it?

Comment: @Benubird When you decrese that buffer, your packets will get dropped instead of queued. Just vanish. Surly that must be even worse than a 2ms latency ?

Comment: @nos no, not really. I'd rather have 100 good results than 100 bad results, and all I'm doing with this is timing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Making the socket receive buffer smaller will not reduce latency.

Instead you need to dequeue all available packets each time. This can be accomplished with a non-blocking socket and edge-triggered [`epoll`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/epoll_wait.2.html) or [`kqueue`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=kqueue&apropos=0&sektion=0&format=html) - on "readable" event read until you get `EWOULDBLOCK`.

As to why you don't get any input with small `SO_RCVBUF` value, look here - http://vger.kernel.org/~davem/skb_sk.html, and here - http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.37/include/net/sock.h#L621

Hope this helps.

Comment: excellent links! Tho, I thought all the packets would be copied into the kernel buffer (which `SO_RCVBUFF` determines the size?). Then, if we have a very large `SO_RCVBUFF`, don't we trash the cache and TLB, having more jitters and so higher latency?

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably platform specific, so, what platform are you targeting?

If you're using Windows then I suggest that you use overlapped I/O and I/O Completion Ports, set the recv buffer to 0 and always have multiple pending `RecvFrom()` calls.

This should a) remove the stack's ability to buffer datagrams when you don't have a `RecvFrom()` pending and b) allow you to process some of the datagrams.

You then tune the number of overlapped operations that you have outstanding so that it's always a few more than you have cores to process the inbound datagrams and you should get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't make sense. Reducing the buffer size doesn't reduce latency. It just increases the probability that incoming datagrams will be dropped, which happens if there isn't room in the socket receive buffer. Your answer about two simultaneous incoming packets doesn't make sense either. Latency is a function of how fast you process the incoming data, not of how large the buffer is.

Comment: The packets don't get timestamped until they are read from the buffer, so the latency (i.e. time between sending and receiving a pacekt, as depicted in the packets timestamp values) depends in part on time spent in the buffer. Dropped packets aren't counted towards the average latency, so a larger buffer produces a higher avg. latency because of the higher average processing time.

Comment: In that case, it's best to drop every packet. You'll have 0ms latency.

Comment: @Benubird: that doesn't make sense either. A large buffer produces more data to process. In the limit you could have a zero buffer size, zero latency, and zero data to process. Somewhere along the line you have to accept that latency isn't the only parameter that needs optimizing, and that reducing socket buffer sizes is basically irrational.

Comment: No. I'm trying to find the best approximation of the actual latency. If a packet is in the buffer for 1ms before it gets processed, than the timestamp on the packet is 1ms after it arrived. To get closer to the real latency therefore, I want to minimize the length of time spent in the buffer - which I can do by ignoring any packets that aren't processed immediately. I am optimizing everything else as well.